# Is it possible to make the navigationcontroller title a button?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

Is it possible to make the navigationcontroller title a button?  but without a button look to it. I want it to be just text that if you click on it a view/actionsheet pops up from the  bottom
If so, can you show me programmatically how I would make it a button?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `TitleView` of `navigationItem` to set a button as title.

Here is what i tried and got it working:

```
UIButton*button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20);
[button setTitle:@"Testing" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[[self navigationItem] setTitleView:button];
```

But if you don't want it to look like a button, you have set the `buttonWithType` to `custom` and set its `backGroundImage` property.

in `btnAction` have your code to show the pop ups.

Comment: Thanks! last thing, im not able to get it to have a clear background. setting backgrouncolor as button.backgroundcolor=[UIcolor clearColor]; does nothing. Have any ideas?

Comment: @AironZagarella Yes, that won't help, the `backgroundColor` property can be seen only on the edges of the button. So if you don't want the title not to look like button, use `UIButton*button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonCustom];` that will have clear background. If you want to add your own image you can set the `backgroundImage` property.

Comment: typo error i meant: if you don't want the title to look like a button